# Select max value on multiple tables, without counting them twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm making a query that allows me to order recipes by score.

### Tables structure

Structure is that a flyer contains one or many `flyer_items`, which can contain one or many `ingredients_to_flyer_item` (this table links ingredient to the flyer item). The other table `ingredient_to_recipe` links the same ingredients but to one or many recipes. Link to .sql file is included at the end.

### Example query

I want to get recipe_id and a SUM of the MAX price weight of each ingredient that are part of the recipe (linked by ingredient_to_recipe), but if a recipe has multiple ingredients that belongs to the same flyers_item, it should be counted once.

```
SELECT itr.recipe_id,
       SUM(itr.weight),
       SUM(max_price_weight),
       SUM(itr.weight + max_price_weight) AS score
FROM
  ( SELECT MAX(itf.max_price_weight) AS max_price_weight,
           itf.flyer_item_id,
           itf.ingredient_id
   FROM
     (SELECT ifi.ingredient_id,
             MAX(i.price_weight) AS max_price_weight,
             ifi.flyer_item_id
      FROM flyer_items i
      JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item ifi ON i.id = ifi.flyer_item_id
      WHERE i.flyer_id IN (1,
                           2)
      GROUP BY ifi.ingredient_id ) itf
   GROUP BY itf.flyer_item_id) itf2
JOIN `ingredient_to_recipe` AS itr ON itf2.`ingredient_id` = itr.`ingredient_id`
WHERE recipe_id = 5730
GROUP BY itr.`recipe_id`
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

The query almost works fine, because most of the results are good, but for some lines, some ingredients are ignored and not counted from the score as they should.

### Test cases

```
| recipe_id | 'score' with current query | what 'score' should be | explanation                                                                 |
|-----------|----------------------------|------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 8376      | 51                         | 51                     | Good result                                                                 |
| 3152      | 1                          | 18                     | Only 1 ingredient having a score of one is counted, should be 4 ingredients |
| 4771      | 41                         | 45                     | One ingredient worth score 4 is ignored                                     |
| 10230     | 40                         | 40                     | Good result                                                                 |
| 8958      | 39                         | 39                     | Good result                                                                 |
| 4656      | 28                         | 34                     | One ingredient worth 6 is ignored                                           |
| 11338     | 1                          | 10                     | 2 ingredients, worth 4 and 5 are ignored                                    |
```

I have a very difficult time finding an easy way to explain it. Let me know if anything else could help.

Here is a link to the demo database to run the query, test examples and test cases: https://nofile.io/f/F4YSEu8DWmT/meta.zip

Thank you very much.

### Update (as asked by Rick James):

Here is the furthest I could make it work. The results are always good, in subquery too, but, I've completely taken out the group by 'flyer_item_id'. So with this query, I get the good score, but if many ingredients of the recipe are the same flyer_item_item, they will be counted multiple times (Like score would be 59 for recipe_id = 10557 instead of the good 56, because 2 ingredients worth 3 are in the same flyers_item). The only thing I need more is to count one MAX(price_weight) per flyer_item_id per recipe,  (which I originally tried by grouping by 'flyer_item_id' over the first group_by ingredient_id.

```
SELECT itr.recipe_id,
       SUM(itr.weight) as total_ingredient_weight,
       SUM(itf.price_weight) as total_price_weight,
       SUM(itr.weight+itf.price_weight) as score
FROM
  (SELECT fi1.id, MAX(fi1.price_weight) as price_weight, ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id as ingredient_id, recipe_id
FROM flyer_items fi1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT flyer_items.id as id, MAX(price_weight) as price_weight, ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id as ingredient_id
    FROM flyer_items
    JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item ON flyer_items.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
    GROUP BY id
) fi2 ON fi1.id = fi2.id AND fi1.price_weight = fi2.price_weight
JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item ON fi1.id = ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
JOIN ingredient_to_recipe ON ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id = ingredient_to_recipe.ingredient_id
GROUP BY ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id) AS itf
INNER JOIN `ingredient_to_recipe` AS `itr` ON `itf`.`ingredient_id` = `itr`.`ingredient_id`
GROUP BY `itr`.`recipe_id`
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Here is the explain, but I'm not sure it's useful as the last working part is still missing:

```
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type   | possible_keys                 | key           | key_len | ref                                                   | rows   | filtered | Extra                           |   |
|----|-------------|--------------------------|------------|--------|-------------------------------|---------------|---------|-------------------------------------------------------|--------|----------|---------------------------------|---|
| 1  | PRIMARY     | itr                      | NULL       | ALL    | recipe_id,ingredient_id       | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                                                  | 151800 | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |   |
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                   | <auto_key0>   | 4       | metadata3.itr.ingredient_id                           | 10     | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
| 2  | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_flyer_item | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                                                  | 249    | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |   |
| 2  | DERIVED     | fi1                      | NULL       | eq_ref | id_2,id,price_weight          | id_2          | 4       | metadata3.ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id      | 1      | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
| 2  | DERIVED     | <derived3>               | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                   | <auto_key0>   | 9       | metadata3.ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id,m... | 10     | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
| 2  | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_recipe     | NULL       | ref    | ingredient_id                 | ingredient_id | 4       | metadata3.ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id      | 40     | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
| 3  | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_flyer_item | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                          | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                                                  | 249    | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |   |
| 3  | DERIVED     | flyer_items              | NULL       | eq_ref | id_2,id,flyer_id,price_weight | id_2          | 4       | metadata3.ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id      | 1      | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
```

### Update 2

I managed to find a query that works, but now I have to make it faster, it takes over 500ms to run.

```
SELECT sum(ff.price_weight) as price_weight, sum(ff.weight) as weight, sum(ff.price_weight+ff.weight) as score, ff.recipe_id FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
       itf.flyer_item_id as flyer_item_id,
       itf.recipe_id,
       itf.weight,
       aprice_weight AS price_weight
FROM
  (SELECT itfin.flyer_item_id AS flyer_item_id,
          itfin.price_weight AS aprice_weight,
          itfin.ingredient_id,
          itr.recipe_id,
          itr.weight
   FROM
     (SELECT ifi2.flyer_item_id, ifi2.ingredient_id as ingredient_id, MAX(ifi2.price_weight) as price_weight
        FROM
          ingredient_to_flyer_item ifi1
        INNER JOIN (
                SELECT id, MAX(price_weight) as price_weight, ingredient_to_flyer_item.ingredient_id as ingredient_id, ingredient_to_flyer_item.flyer_item_id
                FROM ingredient_to_flyer_item
                GROUP BY ingredient_id
            ) ifi2 ON ifi1.price_weight = ifi2.price_weight AND ifi1.ingredient_id = ifi2.ingredient_id
        WHERE flyer_id IN (1,2)
        GROUP BY ifi1.ingredient_id) AS itfin
      INNER JOIN `ingredient_to_recipe` AS `itr` ON `itfin`.`ingredient_id` = `itr`.`ingredient_id`

     ) AS itf
) ff
GROUP BY recipe_id
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Here is the EXPLAIN:

```
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                | key           | key_len | ref                 | rows | filtered | Extra                           |   |
|----|-------------|--------------------------|------------|-------|----------------------------------------------|---------------|---------|---------------------|------|----------|---------------------------------|---|
| 1  | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                         | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                | 1318 | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |   |
| 2  | DERIVED     | <derived4>               | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                         | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                | 37   | 100.00   | Using temporary                 |   |
| 2  | DERIVED     | itr                      | NULL       | ref   | ingredient_id                                | ingredient_id | 4       | itfin.ingredient_id | 35   | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
| 4  | DERIVED     | <derived5>               | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                         | NULL          | NULL    | NULL                | 249  | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |   |
| 4  | DERIVED     | ifi1                     | NULL       | ref   | ingredient_id,itx_full,price_weight,flyer_id | ingredient_id | 4       | ifi2.ingredient_id  | 1    | 12.50    | Using where                     |   |
| 5  | DERIVED     | ingredient_to_flyer_item | NULL       | index | ingredient_id,itx_full                       | ingredient_id | 4       | NULL                | 249  | 100.00   | NULL                            |   |
```

Comment: Instead of a zip file, can you just provide an MCVE as text.

Comment: @Strawberry It would be difficult with that amount on lines even for one simple example. :\

Comment: Remove `ORDER BY price_weight DESC`. Doesn't make sense to order in a subquery.

Comment: In the subquery you have the column `flyer_id`. You are not grouping by this column, so you should use an aggregate function, something  like `max(flyer_id)`. The same bug is present for the column `ingredient_id`.

Comment: Please use prefixed for columns. We can't guess which tables are columns coming from.

Comment: @TheImpaler Query has been updated following your suggestions.

Comment: Have you verified that the subqueries generate the correct value(s)?

Comment: @RickJames I have updated with a version that is less complete but that I'm sure the data is right until that missing part.

Comment: @JeffB. - One of the subqueries says `SELECT id,...`, yet `id` is never used.  Remove it.  And check for other minor errors.

Comment: @JeffB. - to better focus on the 500ms issue, please time each subquery that can be cleanly extracted from the big query.  This may help narrow down what we need to focus on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sounds like "explode-implode".**  This is where the query has a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

1. The `JOIN` gathers the appropriate combinations of rows from the joined tables; *then*
2. The `GROUP BY` `COUNTs`, `SUMs`, etc, giving you inflated values for the aggregates.

There are two common fixes, both involve doing the aggregation separate from the `JOIN`.

Case 1:

```
SELECT  ...
        ( SELECT SUM(x) FROM t2 WHERE id = ... ) AS sum_x,
        ...
    FROM t1 ...
```

That case gets clumsy if you need multiple aggregates from t2, since it allows only one at a time.

Case 2:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT grp,
                  SUM(x) AS sum_x,
                  COUNT(*) AS ct
           FROM t2 ) AS s
    JOIN t1 ON t1.grp = s.grp
```

You have 2 `JOINs` and 3 `GROUP BYs`, so I recommend you debug (and rewrite) your query from the inside out.

```
        SELECT  ifi.ingredient_id,
                MAX(price_weight) as max_price_weight,
                flyer_item_id
            from  flyer_items i
            join  ingredient_to_flyer_item ifi  ON i.id = ifi.flyer_item_id
            where  flyer_id in (1, 2)
            group by  ifi.ingredient_id
```

But I can't help you, since you have not qualified `price_weight` by the table (or an alias) it is in.  (Ditto for some other columns.)

(Actually, `MAX` and `MIN` won't get inflated values; `AVG` will get slightly wrong values; `COUNT` and `SUM` get "wrong" values.)

Hence, I will leave the rest as an "exercise" to the reader".

**INDEXes**

```
itr:  (ingredient_id, recipe_id)  -- for the JOIN and WHERE and GROUP BY
itr:  (recipe_id, ingredient_id, weight)  -- for 1st Update
(There is no optimization available for the ORDER BY and LIMIT)
flyer_items:  (flyer_id, price_weight) -- unless flyer_id is the PRIMARY KEY
ifi:  (flyer_item_id, ingredient_id)
ifi:  (ingredient_id, flyer_item_id)  -- for 1st Update
```

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE for the relevant tables.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

If `ingredient_to_flyer_item` is a many:many mapping tables, please follow the tips [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) .  Ditto for `ingredient_to_recipe`?

`GROUP BY  itf.flyer_item_id` is probably invalid since it does not include the non-aggregated `ifi.ingredient_id`.  See "only_full_group_by".

**Reformulate**

After you finish evaluating the `INDEXes`, try the following.  *Caution: I do not know if it will work correctly.*

```
JOIN  `ingredient_to_recipe` AS itr  ON itf2.`ingredient_id` = itr.`ingredient_id`
```

to

```
JOIN ( SELECT recipe_id,
              ingredient_id,
              SUM(weight) AS sum_weight
           FROM ingredient_to_recipe ) AS itr
```

And change the initial `SELECT` to replace `SUMs` by these computed sums.  (I suspect I have not handled `ingredient_id` correctly.)

What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you running?

Comment: I just updated the query to have all columns (including price_weight) qualified by the table. I tried to deconstruct it, and even rebuilding it from the other way, without success. I understand what is happening, but can't manage to get to a working solution.

Comment: I'm on MySQL 5.7.14. I'm trying your instructions, I'll give an update as soon as possible.

Comment: I have updated with new query, incomplete, but furthest I could go with good data. I also added EXPLAIN.

Comment: See Update 2, I've found a working query, but looking to speed it up.

Comment: @JeffB. - For the 1st update, and after seeing the `EXPLAIN`, I added another index on itr:  `(recipe_id, ingredient_id, weight)`.  The important part is that `recipe_id` is first.

Comment: @JeffB. - And `ingredient_to_flyer_item` needs `INDEX(ingredient_id, flyer_item_id)`, perhaps in both orders.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`)

Answer (score 1):

I've been wanting to take a look at this but unfortunately haven't had time until now. I think this query will give you the results you are looking for.

```
SELECT recipe_id, SUM(weight) AS weight, SUM(max_price_weight) AS price_weight, SUM(weight + max_price_weight) AS score 
FROM (SELECT recipe_id, ingredient_id, MAX(weight) AS weight, MAX(price_weight) AS max_price_weight
      FROM (SELECT itr.recipe_id, MIN(itr.ingredient_id) AS ingredient_id, MAX(itr.weight) AS weight, fi.id, MAX(fi.price_weight) AS price_weight
            FROM ingredient_to_recipe itr 
            JOIN ingredient_to_flyer_item itfi ON itfi.ingredient_id = itr.ingredient_id 
            JOIN flyer_items fi ON fi.id = itfi.flyer_item_id 
            GROUP BY itr.recipe_id, fi.id) ri
      GROUP BY recipe_id, ingredient_id) r
GROUP BY recipe_id
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

It groups first by `flyer_item_id` and then on `MIN(ingredient_id)` to take account of ingredients within a recipe which have the same `flyer_item_id`. Then it sums the results to get the score you want. If I use the query with a

```
HAVING recipe_id IN (8376, 3152, 4771, 10230, 8958, 4656, 11338)
```

clause it gives the following results, which match your "what score should be" column above:

```
recipe_id   weight  price_weight    score   
8376        10      41              51
4771        5       40              45
10230       10      30              40
8958        15      24              39
4656        15      19              34
3152        0       18              18
11338       0       10              10
```

I'm not sure how fast this query will execute on your system, it's comparable to your query on my laptop (which I would expect to be quite a bit slower). I'm pretty sure there are some optimisations possible but again, haven't had time to look into them thoroughly.

I hope this provides you with a bit more help getting to a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood the problem. It seems to me you are grouping by the wrong column `flyer_items.id`. You should be grouping by the column `ingredient_id` instead. If you do this, it makes more sense (to me). Here's how I see it:

```
select
    itr.recipe_id,
    sum(itr.weight),
    sum(max_price_weight),
    sum(itr.weight + max_price_weight) as score
  from (
    select
        ifi.ingredient_id, 
        max(price_weight) as max_price_weight
      from flyer_items i
      join ingredients_to_flyer_item ifi on i.id = ifi.flyer_item_id
      where flyer_id in (1, 2)
      group by ifi.ingredient_id
    ) itf
  join `ingredient_to_recipe` as itr on itf.`ingredient_id` = itr.`ingredient_id`
  group by itr.`recipe_id`
  order by score desc
  limit 0,10;
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I tried that before. The only problem is that if I start grouping by ifi.ingredient_id. If the same ingredient is present in 2 different flyer, it will be counted twice (the price_weight from flyers_item) in the score. Its the same problem but the other way. I try to find a find to combine on flyer_item_id ans ingredient_id. If I can't find a way to make it work as I wish, I'll probably use this query though.

Comment: "counted twice" -- that's my "explode-implode".